# Page Title from a User Control possible?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a `Search.aspx` page  which calls `UCSearch` control. `UCSearch` control does everything like getting what is being searched and what should be displayed, etc. I am trying to give the title to the page. As i dont have any info to write the code in the aspx page, i am thinking to write it in the control. But it is not displaying me when i tried using `Page.Title` in control. What am i doing wrong?? This is in Asp.net and C#.

```
Page.Title = "Search Results for Newark, NY";
```

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2):

Does not:

```
this.Page.Title = "My beautiful title";
```

work?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to get to the ASPX using the Parent property of the control. Cast that property to a Page (it's a WebControl or something similarly generic), then set its Title property. If you have a hierarchy of master pages or are nesting this control in other controls, you may need to traverse the Parent hierarchy for a few more levels.

Answer (score 0):

You could also fire an event from your user control, passing the Title that you would like to display.  You could then handle this event on the page, and set the title.

This does require a small amount of code in your aspx page, however, at least now the user control does not care where the title goes, the parent of the control can worry about it. If ever you want to change where this title goes, or even put it in multiple places, you don't have to change the user control.  Let me know if you want a sample, I'll add it.

If you don't like that idea, then cederlof's answer will work, I just tested it.

```
    protected void helloBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Page.Title = "hello from control";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

** You can use naming container to find the parent control of the current control. Through this way you can move through the page hierarchy.

Quickwatch will help you a lot in figuring out the things and building the statement for quick casting. Do some more research on naming container.

```
var container = userControl.NamingContainer;
if(container is Page)
{
   Page p = container as Page;
   p.Title = "Your Title";
}
```

**
Above is not the exact solution, but can help you it you can usercontrol directly on the page. Unless you need to iterate through the page controls. This was just for an quick help.